# Read data from file in google drive, sort into spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a file containing a lua table, I'm trying to upload the file to google drive then parsing the tables data into specific columns, done from within google spreadsheets.

I have the upload part sorted.

What I'm having trouble doing is reading the file, I'm not even sure where to start. I've had some experience with reading from files with Java, essentially reading each line as a string then figuring out what to do with it from there but I'm not sure if thats possible with Javascript or google sheets.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so able to point me in the right direction on where to start?

I've been going over the google doc reference sheet but nothing seems to relate to what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the documentation for Google Scripts. There are some APIs that may be what you are looking for.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/

For example, if you upload into a Google Document you can use a script to grab the table and read specific rows or cells.

If you make your question a little more specific I might be able to help you figure out exactly which methods could help you.

Comment: After reading around for awhile it doesnt seem like what I'm after is actually possible with just google apps script. I've come up with a different solution, watching for uploaded files in a certain drive folder, downloading, converting to CSV and re-uploading, then importing to the spreadsheet. Thanks for the help though.